# Salesforce platform user must access only an experience site

Tags: community, permissions, profile, licenses, login

I'm in this situation.
All our users with the license "Salesforce platform users" must not access the CRM.
In fact, we are developing a "self-service" community where those types of users can do a variety of things.

Our admins customize the Profile to remove access to any lightning app so that those types of users can't see anything after the login.
But in some cases, using the MyDomain URL they can access the CRM.
How to prevent this scenario?

Comment: The obvious, and cost-saving solution is to switch their licenses to be community-based. There's one distinct down-side, which is that Sharing operates differently.

Comment: this approach would save me from several headaches. unfortunately this is not the asked scenario

Comment: Indeed, which is why it's just a comment. I, personally, would push back against the requirement since it doesn't align well with platform behaviour, and recommend the license change... but that's just me.

Comment: [Login Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_login_flow.htm&language=en_US&type=5)